# How can we count text 'changes' in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can we count text 'changes' in a list?

The list below has 0 'changes'. Everything is the same.

```
['Comcast', 'Comcast', 'Comcast', 'Comcast', 'Comcast', 'Comcast']
```

The list below has 3 changes. First change is Comcast>Sprint, second change is Sprint>AT&T and third change is AT&T>Comcast.

```
['Comcast', 'Comcast', 'Sprint', 'AT&T', 'Comcast', 'Comcast']
```

I Googled this before posting here. Finding unique items seems pretty easy. Finding changes, or switches, seems not so easy.

Comment: Can we see your attempt at doing this? All you need is a loop, an `if`, and a counter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use `itertools.groupby`. This counts the number of "chunks" and subtract one (to get the "boundaries").

```py
from itertools import groupby

lst = ['Comcast', 'Comcast', 'Sprint', 'AT&T', 'Comcast', 'Comcast']

output = sum(1 for _ in groupby(lst)) - 1
print(output) # 3
```

Comment: And...I don't have the CS background like some people here. I majored in finance in college. I definitely thought of getting another degree, but I ran out of money.  I learned data, analytics, programming, etc., all on my own. I read a lot of books, and spent countless hours in front of the screen, but I definitely have knowledge gaps. What's easy for other people, is not necessarily easy for me. If I can do it, I do it. If I can't do it, I post my questions here, and hope someone can help me out. I try to help other people too, based on what I have learned over time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You want to compare elements pairwise, so you can create an iterator to pair up adjacent elements:

```
>>> l = [ 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, ]
>>> list(zip(l[:-1], l[1:]))
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1)]
```

Then iterate over them and test if they're pairwise equal:

```
>>> [x == y for (x, y) in zip(l[0:-1], l[1:])]
[True, False, False, False, True, True]
```

Then count them where they are not equal:

```
>>> sum(1 for (x, y) in zip(l[0:-1], l[1:]) if x != y)
3
```